# Remove comma between [ and {

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to remove the comma that occurs in

```
[,{
```

I've tried two things here with lookbehind and lookahead -

The first is

```
"(?=\\[),(?=})"
```

and the second is putting `(?=[),(?=})` in side Pattern.quote().

I then do a `String.replaceAll(regex,"")` , but it does not work.

Where am I going wrong with lookaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for look-ahead/behind, just use: `str.replaceAll("\\{,\\[", "{[");`.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
String thing = "[,{";
thing.replaceAll("\\[,\\{", "[{");
```

If you want to use a look-behind, I think the syntax is:

```
String pattern = "(?<=\\[),(?=\\{)";
```

(I don't see the "<" in your look-behind.)

Comment: @praks5432: please have a look at this [regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), really the best one I know of. 1+ to Ted's answer, and to your question because you are showing good effort. Keep it up!